# In asp.net, Why page constructor is getting called twice

Tags: asp.net

I have written a constructor in a webpage

```
public partial class TestPage : System.Web.UI.Pag
    {
        public TestPage()
        {
          //  Session["x"] = 10;
        }
  }
```

When I run application from vs2012 in debug mode, Constructor is getting executed twice. Could Anyone let me know why this behaviour?

Edit : this score -2 is been set by anyone ? or is it default one? If it is set by some one, Would like to know why? Thanks.

Comment: Set a breakpoint and look at the call stack.

Comment: This is a partial class, please show us all your code, no mock code. What's happening in the constructor?

Comment: @SLaks: Nothing visible in call stack except 'External code'

Comment: @RajaMoparthi: Disable Just My Code.

Comment: Raja if you don't show us more, we cannot help.

Comment: @Alexander:  This is just a normal webpage which has no controls. I have added a webpage to asp.net project.I have written default constructor for that.I have set that page as 'Start up' page.  there is nothing in 'TestPage.aspx.designer.cs' ( partial class which your asking to present).

Comment: @Alexander: Please refer my comment. Any idea why is it happening?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what would cause the constructor to be called twice in a standard page execution / single load.  Might have something to do with the [page life cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx), and the way that ASP.Net creates the Page variable and uses it (or multiples of it) during execution.

I believe you might intend to use the Page_Load event (as mentioned in the page life cycle) which should only execute once per page load.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["x"] = 10;
}
```

Comment: Yes, Page load event is getting fired once.. But I wonder, If constructor is getting called, Means page is instantiated twice. Still searching for answer.. Anyway thanks for reply..

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be doing anything with Session in your constructor.  Why do you even need to use a constructor on the web page.  Use OnInit() to do your initialization.

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
```

Comment: '@Rick S' .. I am not using session in constructor( it is commented line).  What asp.net is doing with two objects of same page (otherwise why would it is calling constructor twice).

Comment: Are you using Response.Redirect to get to your page?

Comment: No .. This is my default page